# Cannot download Ubuntu to a USB drive. Only option available is to burn to a DVD, which I do not have

Tags: usb, downloads, dvd

After downloading Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, when I click on the program, a window opens which asks me to burn to a disk. Even though I have a USB drive attached (and which is recognized by my computer) it is not available for loading the program.

JohnC

Comment: Dumb question: Which size is your USB stick?

Comment: You are presumable using **Windows**, but do not state that. There are detailed answers on this forum for that.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The answer below works for me. My problem now is what appears to be a common issue with the screen "freezing" after booting Ubuntu. The standard response I keep seeing is that the question has already been addressed but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNetbootin can create a bootable Live USB drive.

UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/608/unetbootin-windows-608.exe/download?use_mirror=ufpr

If using Windows, run the file, select an ISO file or a distribution to download, select a target drive (USB Drive or Hard Disk), then reboot once done. If your USB drive doesn't show up, reformat it as FAT32.

Source: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

Try Rufus https://rufus.akeo.ie

Here is an video as an example https://youtu.be/8xV7gIFzk5Q